# SQL SSIS Importing CSV with specific datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I currently have a table that is importing data from provided CSV's on a regular basis. The issue is that I have 6 columns with data type Decimal(5,2) and are nullable, when I import a file that doesn't report any numbers back it appears as  ",,,,connectionfailed,,,," within these commas are usually the numbers i'm expecting to import into the table.

When SSIS attempts to import these "blank" csv's I get the following error

> Error: 2014-08-04 23:45:01.31     Code: 0xC020901C     Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [9]     Description: There was an error with input column "LaunchBBTime" (85) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (22). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".  End Error

Now when I change all the colums to varchar for testing purposes it imports the blank spaces without a problem, the 2nd issue with this is that SSRS cant calculate averages (in this case for performance) from varchar fields.

My question is can I properly get SSIS to import the blank columns into decimal(5,2) fields without needing to modify the datatypes?

Comment: do you have the right number of commas when there are missing values? are there spaces in between the commas?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not generating these CSV files and idea of how they appear would be: >Value1,value2,value3 while the problem ones are value1,,

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is being caused by spaces i.e. ", ," instead of ",," otherwise the datatype will set the field to its default value (in the case of decimal "0"  or NULL, depending on the "retain null values from the source" property). If this is the case, probably the safest and less performance-expensive solution is passing the csv through a pre-process to remove the white spaces.

Comment: I've reviewed the csv's and they do not contain spaces between the commas.

Comment: Are the fields set as numeric in the flat file connection manager?

Comment: They are actually set as string, i'll try changing that.

Comment: Yes, that could solve the issue. If you change them to numeric they will default to 0; if you prefer default to null then you need to set the flat file source to ‘Retain null values from source’

Answer (score 1):

Pull the columns in as varchar, then in a Derived Column Transformation, create new decimal columns that are populated with something like the following...

```
LEN(LTRIM([InputValue]))==0 ? NULL(DT_NUMERIC,5,2) : (DT_NUMERIC,5,2)[InputValue]
```